# How is Rey's speeder different than Luke's speeder?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, a-new-hope

Rey uses a hovercraft 30+ years after we first see Luke Skywalker's hovercraft in the original trilogy. Given the circumstances of the characters, they were probably both old used vehicles, perhaps even of the same vintage.

**What are the differences between the two vehicles?**  Obviously, their rectangular shapes are oriented perpendicular to one another. But I am asking more about engines, speeds, and manufacturers, if such details have been published.

[image].

[image]

Comment: Rey's speeder looks more like a deoderant stick?

Answer (score 8):

1. [Rey's speeder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rey's_speeder) is 100% custom-buit from scavenged parts

   > Rey’s speeder is an ungainly but powerful repulsorlift vehicle built by the young scavenger from salvaged parts. The speeder is fast and can carry considerable cargo, making it ideal for use scavenging in Jakku’s Graveyard of Ships. (src: [SW Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/reys-speeder))

   There are no stats available for its speed.

   According to *Incredible Cross-Sections* (cited by Wookieepedia)

   > Rey's speeder was powered by powerful twin-turbojet engines reclaimed from an old cargo hauler. Rey chose to mount the engine in a stacked configuration instead of side-by-side and bolted them to powered amplifier intakes from an Imperial gunship. She then customized them with racing swoop afterburners and an array of repulsorlifts taken from crashed X-wing fighters
2. Luke's speeder was a [X-34](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/X-34_landspeeder)

   We don't know much about it from Disney canon, but in EU, we find out:

   - Top speed is 250 km/h. (src:  *The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia*)
   - [old SW Databank](https://web.archive.org/web/20110913060030/http://www.starwars.com/databank/vehicle/xp34landspeeder/index.html) said it was made by Sorosuub corporation.

Comment: And, Luke sold that speeder...

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Luke's speeder was actually his Uncle Owen's - an adult farmer with a reasonably stable income (by Tattooine standards, at least). Rey, on the other hand, is a scavenger living day-by-day. We're basically talking about your dad's pickup truck vs. the motorcycle you cobbled together in the garage.